# jQuery no funciona en mi proyecto de Symfony 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, webpack, symfony4

Estoy comenzando un proyecto en Symfony 4, en él utilizo Bootstrap y FontAwesome. Agregué Bootstrap según la documentación con webpak, al parecer se generó todo bien pues en mis js resultantes veo el código que necesito, pero no me funciona.

Agregué a mi página unos `popover` y `tooltips` de prueba y no trabajan.
Agregué un `navbar` y el menú no se despliega al hacer clic.

En fin que nada trabaja como se supone que deba hacerlo.

El problema es solamente con los js, pues los css están bien.
Por favor puede alguien arrojar algo de luz sobre este asunto.

Gracias de antemano.

Aquí doy mas detalles sobre el asunto.
Primero, mi fichero `asset/js/bootstrap.js` tiene esto:

```
require('bootstrap/js/dist/util');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/popover');

require('bootstrap');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

En `webpack.config.js` tengo esta configuración:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('bootstrap', './assets/js/bootstrap.js')
    .addEntry('fontawesome', './assets/js/fontawesome.js')


    //.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

Nota: Este cambio de arriba es una solución que encontré en un artículo en inglés en este enlace:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080229/symfony-4-webpack-encore-jquery-doesnt-work

Sigue con esto

```
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

En mi plantilla `base.html.twig` tengo esto:

```
{% block javascripts %}
<script src="{{ asset('build/bootstrap.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Fontawesome JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('build/fontawesome.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

También puse un código de un `navbar`, un `Popover` y un `Tooltips` extraído de la documentación oficial de Bootstrap para hacer las pruebas, pero no trabajan.
Ya logré que el jQuery funcione con el cambio que les dije antes, pero ni el `popover` ni el `tooltips` funcionan.

Comment: Podríamos arrojarte más luz si subieras el código :D. Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ganar tu primera medalla y aprender a formular una buena pregunta.

Comment: Como lo cargas a Bootstrap? Con la información que has dejado, es literalmente imposible ayudarte, agrega el código del archivo  donde estas teniendo el problema

Answer (score 0):

Hola nuevamente: buscando en stackoverflow.com acabo de encontra una solucion bastante simple al problema del jQuery.

Solo deben cambiar en `webpack.config.js`

```
.enableSingleRuntimeChunk() por .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

En el articulo en ingles dicen que es probable recibir una advertencia pero yo recompile todo sin problemas.

Todavía que por resolver los popover y tooltip.
Así que no doy por cerrado este tema.

Comment: Porfavor añadí la fuente de tu respuesta (enlace a la respuesta en StackOverflow en Inglés)

Comment: Disculpa es que soy nuevo es esto creo que debo editar mi pregunta y dar mas detalles.

Comment: Ya actualice mi pregunta con mas detalles, la solucion al jquery la encontre aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080229/symfony-4-webpack-encore-jquery-doesnt-work